# Read HTTP requests from generic stream in C#

Tags: c#, http, httprequest

I'm creating an application to sniff HTTP traffic which currently uses SharpPcap to collect and reconstruct HTTP messages from TCP packets and provides them via a Stream class.

Ideally I don't want to have to implement the whole HTTP parsing process on top of that, but I can't find any way to use HttpWebRequest or HttpWebResponse to just read a stream rather than initiating a request itself.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is this: https://github.com/chmorgan/packetnet-connections or if you can work at a higher level (proxy rather than packet capture) the FiddlerCore library does this nicely & also supports HTTPS decoding.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd use FiddlerCore as it's proxy based, I could really do with something that captures packets. I'll investigate packetnet-connections - thanks!

Comment: packetnet-connections looks promising, but it doesn't handle the main issue of how to parse the HTTP message.